# How can I add a field to a queryset and populate it within a loop?

Tags: django

I have a queryset `foo` that contains a couple thousand items. Now I would like to add a field `bar` to this queryset whose value depends on some logic embedded in a loop. So I want to iterate `foo` and enrich `bar` for each item.

```
# Views.py

def example(request):

    [..]

    # Create `Bar` field for queryset
    foo.annotate(bar='')

    # Iterate queryset
    for item in foo:

        [..] # logic that returns a string
 
            # Populate field 'bar'
            item.bar = 'example_string'
```

However, it already breaks at `foo.annotate(bar='')` returning

> QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to annotate with a non-empty string you can sue:

```
from django.db.models import Value

foo.annotate(bar=Value(''))
```

That being said, it makes not much sense to annotate with an empty string, you simply set an attribute on your `Foo` objects. I would also advise to wrap the items in a list, since subscripting will otherwise make new database queries.

Comment: that worked, but I didn't get that list part totally

Comment: @Jonas: if you use `foo[1]`, Django will make an extra query to fetch the second item, that will thus *not* contain the value you assigned with `item.bar = ...`. If you first wrap it in a list, so `items = list(foo.annotate(...))` and  then annotate these, then `items[1]` will not make a new query, but use the old object.